# How to mock private method and returns different results C#

Tags: c#

I need to add two unit tests for the code snippet below. There are 3 points in order to add tests for this method.

```
    private async Task<AuthenticationResult> ValidateMsiCredential(MsiCredentials msiCredentials, ComputeResourceDocument computeEntity, string resourceId)
    {
        if (msiCredentials == null)
        {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
        }
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(msiCredentials.ClientSecret));
        var cred = new ClientAssertionCertificate(msiCredentials.ClientId, cert);

        var authority = msiCredentials.AuthenticationEndpoint + "/" + computeEntity.Identity.TenantId;
        using (var authContext = new AuthenticationContextWrapper(authority, false))
        {
            var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, cred).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return authResult.Result;
        }
    }
```

1. I mocked a msiCredential,and received " System.FormatException : The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

   ```
        var msiCredential = A.Fake<MsiCredentials>();
        msiCredential.ClientId = "sai-id";
        msiCredential.ClientSecret = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAABkC==";
        msiCredential.ClientSecretUrl = "sai-url";
   ```
2. Is it possible to mock different return results when I use reflection to call this private method? Since AcquireTokenAsync is a http response from azure aad service. So I need to mock throws exceptions.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess the problem is the `Convert.FromBase64String` is failing because your faked client secret isn't valid base64

Comment: Is there a good way to use in my scenario?